# Ruby/Rails - Get the previous Friday? (Friday of last week)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Is there a way to get the previous Friday's date in Rails?  I've seen ways to get the closest Friday, or the previous Monday or Sunday, but I specifically need the last Friday.

So up until and including Friday of this current week, it'd be the previous week's Friday. Then starting on Saturday, it'd be the Friday a day before.

For example:

- Saturday, March 4th through Friday, March 10th -> Friday, March 3rd
- Saturday, March 11th through Friday, March. 17th -> Friday, March 10th

Comment: Just subtract 1 day, while the day isn't Friday...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without any conditionals. This will accept a Date, Time, or DateTime object.

```
def prior_friday(date)
  days_before = (date.wday + 1) % 7 + 1
  date.to_date - days_before
end
```

Now you can do any of these:

```
>> prior_friday(Date.today)
=> Fri, 24 Mar 2017
>> prior_friday(Date.tomorrow)
=> Fri, 31 Mar 2017
>> prior_friday(Date.new(2017,4,4))
=> Fri, 31 Mar 2017
>> prior_friday(Time.now)
=> Fri, 24 Mar 2017
>> prior_friday(DateTime.tomorrow)
=> Fri, 31 Mar 2017
>> prior_friday(1.year.from_now)
=> Fri, 30 Mar 2018
```

For different days of the week, change the integer added to `date.wday` before the mod is applied:

```
def prior_monday(date)
  days_before = (date.wday + 5) % 7 + 1
  date.to_date - days_before
end
```

Or make a universal method:

```
def prior_weekday(date, weekday)
  weekday_index = Date::DAYNAMES.reverse.index(weekday)
  days_before = (date.wday + weekday_index) % 7 + 1
  date.to_date - days_before
end
```

Examples run on Saturday, August 4, 2018:

```
>> prior_weekday(Date.today, 'Saturday')
Sat, 28 Jul 2018
>> prior_weekday(Date.today, 'Friday')
Fri, 03 Aug 2018
>> prior_weekday(Date.tomorrow, 'Friday')
Fri, 03 Aug 2018
>> prior_weekday(Date.tomorrow, 'Saturday')
Sat, 04 Aug 2018
>> prior_weekday(Date.tomorrow, 'Sunday')
Sun, 29 Jul 2018
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: what point is making this Friday? this one `date.wday + 1` ?
what if I want other day e.g. Monday.

Comment: @SohairAhmad It's the number added after `date.wday`. Adding 0 gives you the prior Saturday. Adding 5 instead of 1 will give you the prior Monday.

Comment: Hmm this gives a reverse offset, less intuitive.  Use the following for more intuative 1 is monday, 2 is tuesday, 3 is thursday and so on. `days_before = (date.wday - (day_of_week_offset + 1)) % 7 + 1`, though I see the answer below works for rails 5.2, so will be using that instead.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [#prev_occurring](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-prev_occurring) since Rails 5.2:

```
Date.today.prev_occurring(:friday)
```

Comment: I have just Googled this question and used this answer. When I was going to upvote it, I got an error and realised that I was the one answering it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension, you can use it as `Time.last_friday` or `Time.now.last_friday`

```
class Time
  def self.last_friday
    time = (Time.now - 1.day)
    while !time.friday?
      time -= 1.day
    end
    time
  end
  def last_friday
    time = (self - 1.day)
    while !time.friday?
      time -= 1.day
    end
    time
  end
end
```

Comment: Got it. So its like brute forcing it kind of. A guess and check, if you will.

Comment: I don't think you want to extend Time, as that would limit the method's usefulness to Time objects. See my answer for a simple method that works with all Rails date/time objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with.

```
def prior_weekday(date, index_of_target_day)
  if date.wday == index_of_target_day
    date - 1.week
  else
    date - (date.wday - index_of_target_day) % 7
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
> MONDAY_INDEX = 1
> prior_weekday(Date.parse('2018-11-16'), MONDAY_INDEX) # 11/16 is a Friday
=> Mon, 12 Nov 2018
```